# Why Timer corrupt my data when i plot more than 2 values?

Tags: python, plot, timer, serial-port, wxmpl

I use Timer for plotting and storing at same time. When i plot 2 values, no losing data from serial port(60 lines in minute, my device=1Hz). But when i try to plot more than 2 values, it corrupts the data(~40 lines in minute).

**1.Should i try `thread` or `queue` instead of `wx.Timer`?**

**2.Why does `wx.Timer` corrupt my data? or what's the problem?**

**3.Should i use serial port func. inside `wx.Timer`??**

Where am i doing wrong and what? I need your help. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import wxmplot
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import numpy as np

is_wxPhoenix = 'phoenix' in wx.PlatformInfo
if is_wxPhoenix:
    PyDeadObjectError = RuntimeError
else:
    from wx._core import PyDeadObjectError



class myframe ( wx.Frame ):          #Panel ###(reading, saving, plotting as a real-time from serial port)

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.plotframe = None

        self.toggleBtn17 = wx.ToggleButton( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"GRAPH", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.toggleBtn17, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.toggleBtn171 = wx.ToggleButton( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Store", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.toggleBtn171.Hide()
        bSizer1.Add( self.toggleBtn171, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.toggleBtn4 = wx.ToggleButton( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Save", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.toggleBtn4.Hide()
        bSizer1.Add( self.toggleBtn4, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.timer1 = wx.Timer()
        self.timer1.SetOwner( self, 1 )

        self.timer2 = wx.Timer()
        self.timer2.SetOwner( self, 2 )
        self.timer2.Start( 1000 )                           ### running when app begins

        self.timer3 = wx.Timer()
        self.timer3.SetOwner( self, 3 )
        self.timer3.Start( 15000 )       #999               ### running when app begins

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )

        # Connect Events
        self.toggleBtn17.Bind( wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.plot_aio )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer1_plot, id=1 )

        self.toggleBtn171.Bind( wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.store_f )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer2_store, id=2 )

        self.toggleBtn4.Bind( wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.save_f )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer3_save, id=3 )

        self.x1 = np.array([])              # coming data from serial port should list. in wxmplot, numpy array is the best choice for appending data
        self.y1 = np.array([])       
        self.y2 = np.array([])
        self.y3 = np.array([])

        self.store = []
        self.store_tempr = []

        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM9', 9600)

    def ShowPlotFrame(self, do_raise=True, clear=True):   
        "make sure plot frame is enabled, and visible"
        if self.plotframe is None:
            self.plotframe = wxmplot.MultiPlotFrame(rows=3, cols=3, panelsize=(350, 275))
            self.has_plot = False
        try:
            self.plotframe.Show()
        except PyDeadObjectError:
            self.plotframe = wxmplot.MultiPlotFrame(rows=3, cols=3, panelsize=(350, 275))
            self.plotframe.Show()
        if do_raise:
            self.plotframe.Raise()
        if clear:
            self.plotframe.panel.clear()
            #self.plotframe.reset_config()

    def plot_aio( self, event ):                    ### plot button(timer 1)             
        if self.timer1.IsRunning():
            self.timer1.Stop()
            print("timer1  stopped")
        else:
            print("tgl_timer1  starting...")
            self.ShowPlotFrame()        
            self.timer1.Start( 500 )    

    def store_f( self, event ):                     ### store in the numpy array button but both Timer activated and Button hidden(timer 2)
        event.Skip()
        #=======================================================================
        # if self.timer2.IsRunning():
        #     self.timer2.Stop()
        #     print("saving stopped")
        # else:
        #     print("saving_timer2 is starting...")
        #     self.timer2.Start( 1000 )
        #=======================================================================

    def save_f( self, event ):                       ### del the storing data button for not using more memory (both Timer activated and Button hidden)
        event.Skip()
        #=======================================================================
        # if self.timer3.IsRunning():
        #     self.timer3.Stop()
        #     print("timer 3  stopped")
        # else:
        #     print("tgl_timer 3  starting...")
        #     self.timer3.Start( 10000 )           #501  
        #=======================================================================

    def timer1_plot( self, event ):                 ### PLOT STORED DATA (not button but entegrated with plot_aio func which is button)            
        for line in self.store_tempr:
            data=line.split(b",")
            if data[0] == b"$GNGGA":
                tim2=data[1]
                timm=float(tim2)
                tim=timm+30000                            
                hour = tim//10000
                minute = (tim//100)%100
                second = tim%100
                zaman = hour*3600 + minute*60 + second    
                self.x1 = np.append(self.x1, zaman)  

                latitude=data[2]
                lat=float(latitude)
                lat1=int(lat/100)
                lat2=(lat%100)/60
                lati=lat1+lat2
                self.y2 = np.append(self.y2, lati)

                longitude=data[4]
                lon=float(longitude)
                lon1=int(lon/100)
                lon2=(lon%100)/60
                longi=lon1+lon2
                self.y3 = np.append(self.y3, longi)

                altitude=data[9]
                self.y1 = np.append(self.y1, float(altitude))

                self.ShowPlotFrame()  
                self.plotframe.plot(self.x1, self.y1, panel=(0, 0), labelfontsize=6) 
                self.plotframe.plot(self.x1, self.y3, panel=(0, 1), color='red',  labelfontsize=6)
                self.plotframe.plot(self.y1, self.x1, panel=(1, 0), color='black', labelfontsize=5) 
                self.plotframe.plot(self.y2, self.y3, panel=(1, 1), fullbox=False) 
                self.plotframe.plot(self.x1, self.y1, panel=(0, 2), labelfontsize=6) 
                self.plotframe.plot(self.x1, self.y3, panel=(2, 1), color='red',  labelfontsize=6)
                self.plotframe.plot(self.y1, self.x1, panel=(2, 0), color='black', labelfontsize=5) 
                self.plotframe.plot(self.y2, self.y3, panel=(2, 2), fullbox=False) 


        del self.store_tempr[:]

    def timer2_store( self, event ):                ### STORE and WRITE TO .TXT FILE AND DELETE FROM THE LIST (not button)
        print( "storing and saving")
        for line in self.ser:
            self.store.append(line)
            self.store_tempr.append(line)


    def timer3_save( self, event ):                  ### DELETE STORED DATA IN THE LIST (not button)
        with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\4n.txt","a") as f: 
            for line in self.store:            
                f.writelines(str(line)+ "\n")
            del self.store[:]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = myframe(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not need to use Threads or Queues instead of wx.Timers. But, I also think you actually need only 1 `wx.Timer` that checks for and grabs data from the serial port (or other data source).   I would suggest that the handler for the `wx.Timer` events (probably running at ~2Hz if you expect data at 1Hz) should do the following:

1. check for new data. if there is not new data, return immediately, waiting for next `wx.Timer` event.
2. if there is new data, parse and do the calculations based on that data right away and append it to the data arrays within that event handler.  Just drop all the storing and later deleting of temporary data and have you `self.x1`, `self.y1` etc up-to-date when the data-event-handler ends.  All those `del XXX` in your code -- especially since one event handler deletes data created in another place - look like they could be a problem.
3. and then update the plots. If you believe the plotting will be slow, you could use a second timer event that looks at whether the length of `self.x1` has changed and remake the plot(s).  But, I believe you should not need to use a second timer, and can just update the plots in the data-event-handler.

For an example of how this might be done, see https://github.com/newville/wxmplot/blob/master/examples/stripchart.py
That uses just one `wx.Timer` that fetches new data and updates the plot.  Note that it uses `wxmplot.PlotPanel.update_line()` which is much faster at updating an existing plot than redoing `wxmplot.PlotPanel.plot()` for each new data set.

The `next_data()` function in that example is a bit simpler and more deterministic than what you would need to do to read data from the serial port.  But you're already doing that part and what you're doing doesn't look too hard or slow.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. It saved me a ton of time. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Can i ask a question about _saving to .txt file(every 15 seconds)_ if you dont mind? I applied your stripchart.py example for mine, it is good for plotting and updating, but i couldn't call `def next_data()` more than once without depreciating data or missing data. Except one, others get data as a **NoneType**. Eventhough my device running at 1Hz, when i set timer(10ms or 500ms), i couldnt get same data more than once because of  **NoneType**.

Comment: that is hard to answer within a SO comment.  Once you have data arrays, those should not be hard to dump to a disk file.  There are many approaches to doing that.   There is not anything specific in your comment about why you are getting `NoneType`. If you need help with that, ask a separate question (and of course complete and good and including actual code) about that topic.

Comment: @M Newville. Sir, i posted it as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740673/how-can-i-get-data-without-blocking